# Order results inside and outside of union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, union

I have come upon what I'd say is complex sql query to which I need to implement better ordering. I'll give you a simpler version and hopefully the solution will apply to the original.

Suppose I have two tables to which I am applying `UNION`. I want to order the results for each of those tables and then the resulting table itself.

Let's say I have these tables:

Folders:

```
Name    CreateDate
------------------
Music   2015-11-12
Videos  2012-11-12
```

Files:

```
Name    CreateDate
------------------
file1   2014-11-12
file2   2013-11-12
```

User is able to sort them either by Name or CreateDate, but in the result Folders always must appear first.

I would write something like this:

```
Select *
From (
    Select Name, CreateDate, 1 as tableOrder
    From Folders
    Order by
        CASE WHEN @NameOrder = 1 THEN Name END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @DateOrder = 1 THEN CreateDate END ASC
    UNION
    Select Name, CreateDate, 2 as tableOrder
    From Files
    Order by
        CASE WHEN @NameOrder = 1 THEN Name END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @DateOrder = 1 THEN CreateDate END ASC    
    )
Order by tableOrder
```

But I know that I can use order by only after union. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the `UNION` in a derived table. Order it's result, put tableOrder first in the `ORDER BY`:

```
select * from
(
    Select Name, CreateDate, 1 as tableOrder
    From Folders
    UNION
    Select Name, CreateDate, 2 as tableOrder
    From Files
) dt
Order by tableOrder,
         CASE WHEN @NameOrder = 1 THEN Name END ASC,
         CASE WHEN @DateOrder = 1 THEN CreateDate END ASC
```

Comment: So simple! Now I'm dumbfounded how could I not see this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your query has multiple issues.  First, the ordering of a query is determined *only* by `ORDER BY` in the outer-most query.  Second, you are using `UNION`, which incurs extra overhead to remove duplicates. 
To fix these problems:

```
Select Name, CreateDate, which
From ((Select Name, CreateDate, 1 as tableOrder
       From Folders
      ) UNION ALL
      (Select Name, CreateDate, 2 as tableOrder
       From Files
      )
     ) ff
Order by tableOrder,
         (CASE WHEN @NameOrder = 1 THEN Name END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN @DateOrder = 1 THEN CreateDate END) ASC   ;
```